# trying to get return info from one function to another

Tags: python, function, return

I'm trying to use functions (something that I am inherently bad at apparentlyXD) and am trying to get the return statement info from the first and then use it in the second. Both are for rolling dice, so the first function is to have the first set returned, which is to be then used in the second function to give the user the option to reroll. What am I doing wrong in this implementation that it's not recognizing the original dieset list?

```
def rollDie():
   die1 = 2
   die2 = 2
   die3 = 2
   die4 = 4
   die5 = 5

   dieset = [die1,die2,die3,die4,die5]
   print(dieset)

   return dieset


def reRoll1():

rollDie() 
reroll1 = input("Would you like to reroll? Yes or No: ")
if reroll1 == "no":
    dieset = [die1,die2,die3,die4,die5]
else:
    count = 0
    times = int(input("How many die would you like to reroll? "))
    while count < times:
        whichreroll = input("Reroll die: ")
        if whichreroll == "1":
            die1 = random.randint(1,6)
        else:
            die1 
        if whichreroll == "2":
            die2 = random.randint(1,6)
        else:
            die2
        if whichreroll == "3":
            die3 = random.randint(1,6)
        else:
            die3
        if whichreroll == "4":
            die4 = random.randint(1,6)
        else:
            die4
        if whichreroll == "5":
            die5 = random.randint(1,6)
        else:
            die5
        dieset = [die1,die2,die3,die4,die5]
        count += 1
        print(dieset)   

        return dieset   
reRoll1()
```

It's telling me "local variable 'die1' referenced before assignment" but rollDie() comes first. If anyone could explain this to me it would be greatly appreciated:D

Comment: `die1`, `die2`, ... are defined in `rollDie` function, So you can't reference them in `reRoll1` function and please fix your code formatting.

Answer (score 0):

to be able to reference the returned data from rollDie() you need to assign it to a variable i.e.:

```
dieset = rollDie()
```

However, you also have a problem at:

```
if reroll1 == 'no':
    dieset = [die1, die2, die3, die4, die5]
```

Here, you are referencing the variables die1, die2... but they haven't been assigned any value.

As a workaround, you could assign these variables an arbitrary value, say 0:

```
dieset = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

BUT... then in your conditionals, you reference variables die1, die2...; which haven't actually been assigned. So you could forget all about the variable dieset, and assign die1, die2... directly:

```
die1, die2, die3, die4, die5 = rollDie() if reroll1 == 'yes' else [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

this way, you can then to reference the values simply as `die1` etc. in your following conditions.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting the desired behavior because `die1`, `die2`, `...` are not global variables, but you are treating them as such.

In other words `die1` within `reRoll1()` is different than `die1` within `rollDie()`.

To get what you want, you should either work with return values, or initialize the variables globally by writing there definition on the same indentation level as where you call `reRoll1()`